# Perl SSLeay certificate and key as string

Tags: perl

I have some problem with SSLeay in Perl. And I've no experience of Perl to speak of so I need your help!

I'm trying to communicate whit Apple Push Notification Service (APNS). That's kind of easy, but I can't use files to store the certificate and the RSA private key. This code should be run from a database.

This works:

```
Net::SSLeay::CTX_use_RSAPrivateKey_file( $ctx, 'key.pem', &Net::SSLeay::FILETYPE_PEM );
die_if_ssl_error("private key");

Net::SSLeay::CTX_use_certificate_file( $ctx, 'cert.pem', &Net::SSLeay::FILETYPE_PEM );
die_if_ssl_error("certificate");
```

But as I said earlier, I cannot use files. So I tried this:

```
$private_key = '----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE [...]';

my $rsa_private = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_private_key($private_key);
Net::SSLeay::CTX_use_RSAPrivateKey( $ctx, $rsa_private );
die_if_ssl_error("private key");

Net::SSLeay::CTX_use_certificate_file( $ctx, 'cert.pem', &Net::SSLeay::FILETYPE_PEM );
die_if_ssl_error("certificate");
```

But now I get Segmentation fault at row 7. If I exit at row 6, no error occurs.
What am I doing wrong at this step?

Next step is to get the certificate from a string as well. The documentation for SSLeay says the second parameter of CTX_use_certificate must be a x509 object. So I try to create one:

```
my $private_key = '----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE [...]';
my $certificate = '----BEGIN CERTIFICATE [...]';

my $rsa_private = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_private_key($private_key);
Net::SSLeay::CTX_use_RSAPrivateKey( $ctx, $rsa_private );
die_if_ssl_error("private key");

my $x509 = Crypt::OpenSSL::X509->new_from_string($certificate);    
Net::SSLeay::CTX_use_certificate( $ctx, $x509 );
die_if_ssl_error("certificate");
```

But that gives me:

```
certificate 9530: 1 - error:140BF10C:SSL routines:SSL_SET_CERT:x509 lib
9530: certificate
```

Do you have any tip or idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work if Net::SSLeay version is equal or higher then 1.45

```
my $pkey = '----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY ... (PEM formated)';
my $cert = '----BEGIN CERTIFICATE ... (PEM formated)';

my $bio_key = Net::SSLeay::BIO_new(Net::SSLeay::BIO_s_mem()) or die;
Net::SSLeay::BIO_write($bio_key, $pkey) or die "no key";
my $evp_pkey = Net::SSLeay::PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey($bio_key, 
               sub { RETURN PASSWORD IF ANY NESSESARY}) or die "no evp_pkey structure";
Net::SSLeay::CTX_use_PrivateKey($ctx, $evp_pkey);
Net::SSLeay::BIO_free($bio_key);

my $bio_cert = Net::SSLeay::BIO_new(Net::SSLeay::BIO_s_mem()) or die;
Net::SSLeay::BIO_write($bio_cert, $cert) or die "no cert";
my $x509 = Net::SSLeay::PEM_read_bio_X509($bio_cert) or die "no x509 structure";
Net::SSLeay::CTX_use_certificate($ctx, $x509) or die ;
Net::SSLeay::BIO_free($bio_cert);
```

Comment: Thanks! I solved it a few month ago, but with a really messy solution. I'm sure your example will help me!